# Eclipse GUI, XML graphical layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Is there any way to get a ruler line in the Android XML graphical layout view in Eclipse.

If you don't know which layout I am talking about, it's this one on the right.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Im not sure what are you talking about, but if you want a separator or something like that just insert a LinearLayout and fill it with a background `android:background="color`

Comment: No I need a ruler or grid to let me know what the X and Y coordinates are in the view, on the image above on the right, like an overlay on the screen just for me to see not the user. I need to know exact coordinates for multi touch events.

Answer (score 0):

you could use absolute layout (not recommended, as it is being deprecated) or relative layout and call the getX() and getY() functions of your Views (Buttons) and print them for debugging purposes. Ive never heard of a dev ruler like your talking about... if you provide a few more details about your project I can help you more.

Comment: I can get the points in the Logcat already, using my Android phone. I click on a specific point on an image to open a alert dialog when that point is clicked. I can get the exact point to click and get the dialog to open but I would like to get a measure of the area around it so I can cover the area and not just the exact point say (x=5,y=150).  The ruler would be really easy as I have ten points on the image.

Comment: why do you need to declare set a listener to the specific region containing the button when you can just declare a listener on the button...? this could also be an issue when you try to install your app on a phone of different screen dimensions, your buttons might not match up with your active click regions.

Comment: Sorry it's not a button, that image above was just a example of the graphical XML layout, it's an image that I'm clicking on and I have pins in areas of the image, when the pins are clicked a alert dialog comes out on the screen with info about that part of the image.

Comment: why dont you just create a logger and log the getX() and getY() coordinates of your 10 points, then hard code them in? Im sorry to tell you but Ive never heard of a native pixel ruler in android sdk